# How can a Number Represented without Normalization Technique?

Tags: floating-point

Consider the following floating point Representation

[image]

Mantissa is pure fraction in signed magnitude form . What is the representation of the binary number 1111.1111 $\times 2^{2} $ in hexadecimal **without** Normalization .

**My Approach**

bias = 64

$(-1)^{S} (1.M)_{2} \times 2^{\text{E-bias}}$  This is normalized Representation .

But here we are asked to find the Not Normalized Representation that means we need to store    1111.1111 $\times 2^{2} $ as such . But How can this be done ?

$1.1111111 \times 2^{5}$

Do I need to add bias when storing in Not Normalized form ?

- here bias is 64 (excess 64 representation) i.e Sign is 0 , Exponent will be 69 and Mantissa is 255 [ this is same as Normalized Representation]

OR Do Not need to add bias and store number as it is ?

- here , Sign is 0 , Exponent will be 5 , Mantissa will be 255

Please confirm which is the correct Representation give some links to online resources stating the correctness of the approach as well

Comment: Hint: $10.34 \times 10^3 = 10340$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus , I have added some more useful work . Can you check now ?